# html table drag and drop not working in zend framework

Tags: php, jquery, html, zend-framework, drag-and-drop

I followed this link for re-ordering of tables.
http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dynamic-dragn-drop-with-jquery-and-php/

It is working fine in normal php, but when i want to integrate it in zend framework,I am getting error saying "unknown is not a method" at `$(#tag).sortable()`. I am not able find what the problem is. May be zend library not supporting html 5.

Please help me for finding the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see your relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in Zend, since the code you have posted is javascript (jQuery).

Your problem is that you are calling the $() function with non-string parameter.

`$(#tag).sortable()` should be `$("#tag").sortable()`